# Which C# compiler version to compile C# 7.3 with the CSharpCodeProvider class?

Tags: c#, csharpcodeprovider

I would like to use the Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider class to compile C# 7.3 code. The compiler version is specified in an IDictionary that is taken as input when a new CSharpCodeProvider is created; for example, { "CompilerVersion", "v4.0" }. "v4.0" is not sufficient, as it does not recognize v7.3 as a compiler option.

Answer (score 11):

The newer compiler versions are no longer shipped as part of the .NET Framework proper, and therefore cannot be by default accessed via the legacy CodeDOM API (which includes `Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider`).

Instead if you wish to use the CodeDOM API with the newer compilers, you want to use `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider` which is a subclass of `Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider`. This class is available in the Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform nuget package.

For non web applciations you also need to provide a configuration or environment variable that provides a path to C# compiler you want to use (A copy ships in the nuget package, so you can use that). See https://github.com/aspnet/RoslynCodeDomProvider for details.

Comment: For web.config ? `compiler language="c#;cs;csharp"` ?

Comment: @Kiquenet When you add the nuget package, it would normally run powershell script to update web.config. If not, what you want is: `<compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=3.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:7.0 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701;612;618" />`. Of course, there are things you can adjust in that if needed.