# C# CodeDomCompiler. error CS1056: Unexpected character '$'

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, codedom, csharpcodeprovider

My code is this:

```
public static bool CompileClient(out string[] errors)
{
    using (CodeDomProvider provider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp"))
    {
        CompilerParameters cp = new CompilerParameters
        {
            GenerateExecutable = true,
            OutputAssembly = $"./hi.exe",
            CompilerOptions = "/optimize",
            TreatWarningsAsErrors = false
        };
        if (provider.Supports(GeneratorSupport.EntryPointMethod))
            cp.MainClass = "Namespace.Program";

        CompilerResults cr = provider.CompileAssemblyFromFile(cp, Directory.GetFiles("./Sourcecode/")); // Invoke compilation

        if (cr.Errors.Count > 0)
        {
            List<string> _errors = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < cr.Errors.Count; i++)
                _errors.Add(cr.Errors[i].ToString());
            errors = _errors.ToArray();
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            errors = null;
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

The .cs Files in /Sourcecode/ contain the following code:
`$"Hello {name}"`

When I compile the Files I get this Error: `error CS1056: Unexpected character '$'.`

**Is there a way to fix the error without using string + string or string.Format()?**
maybe changing the version or something..?

Answer (score 2):

The $ notation for "string interpolations" (basically shorthand for string.Format()) was introduced in c# version 6, so you need a compiler that supports at least that version.

This answer might help:

[Which C# compiler version to compile C# 7.3 with the CSharpCodeProvider class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50241006/which-c-sharp-compiler-version-to-compile-c-sharp-7-3-with-the-csharpcodeprovide)